# Does android backup api work on real devices?

Tags: android, android-backup-service

I have reed Google instructions to backup data using backup api. And i write simple test [program](https://github.com/jhdevs/TestMyBackup) to check how does it work (MainActivity + BackupAgent for shared preferences).

On AVD emulator with different API's everything works perfect, but on a real device i can't get data back after reinstall application.

I have tested it in different ways:

- Google recomendations from [backup data](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html)
- adb shell bmgr commands / wait 24+ hours for automatic backup event
- transports com.google.android.gms/.backup.BackupTransportService and android/com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransport
- additional "bmgr restore" command / additional calling requestRestore()
- using FileBackupHelper / SharedPreferencesBackupHelper
- different devices Nexus4, Nexus7, Samsung Galaxy, Acer a501 (every device has all "Backup & reset" settings on)
- install application from Android Studio / install signed apk from sdcard / i even posted my application on Google Play and tried to install application from there
- uninstall applicatation using adb / from device applciations / wipe my device

In  logcat i can see that my package is in system backup list and BackupHelper.onCreate() is called.

```
    03-14 18:29:14.716  16355-16355/com.jh.testmybackup D/BACKUP﹕ ThebackupAgent.onCreate()
    03-14 18:29:14.716  16355-16367/com.jh.testmybackup V/BackupServiceBinder﹕ doBackup() invoked
    03-14 18:29:14.716  16355-16367/com.jh.testmybackup D/BackupHelperDispatcher﹕ handling existing helper 'com.jh.testmybackup' android.app.backup.SharedPreferencesBackupHelper@41e1ad90
    03-14 18:29:14.716      311-407/? D/PerformBackupTask﹕ starting agent for backup of BackupRequest{pkg=com.jh.testmybackup}
    03-14 18:29:14.716      311-407/? D/BackupManagerService﹕ awaiting agent for ApplicationInfo{42c80f98 com.jh.testmybackup}
    03-14 18:29:14.716    311-27709/? D/BackupManagerService﹕ agentConnected pkg=com.jh.testmybackup agent=android.os.BinderProxy@426b4240
    03-14 18:29:14.716      311-407/? I/BackupManagerService﹕ got agent android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub$Proxy@42979528
    03-14 18:29:14.716      311-407/? D/PerformBackupTask﹕ invokeAgentForBackup on com.jh.testmybackup
    03-14 18:29:15.176      311-407/? I/PerformBackupTask﹕ Backup pass finished.
```

But nothing helps. **After reinstall application i don't get my data back**.

After all, i tried to find some information about this problem, but don't found any solution. I found some example applications (stackoverflow.com/questions/12402749/examples-of-application-used-android-backup-services no reputation for link) and tried to install them on my devices, and they also don't restore nothing after reinstall.

I fill myself very stupid. Am i the only one with such problem?

Comment: Are you trying to backup on an app signed with the same key? I think (but do not know) that files stored for one key are salted with said key, and because of this you can't cross data from two different key-signed-apks. I don't know if this is what you were doing, but a friendly heads up, is all.

Comment: @MeetTitan i tried to do full test cycle (install - set preferences - call dataChanged - run bmgr commands - uninstall - install again - try to read preferences) for same .apk file

Comment: Did you get an answer to this ? I've implemented backup API, and I've noticed it works on emulators and Motorola devices, but not on Samsung devices...

Answer (score 0):

Check your Manifest file to see if under application you have android:allowBackup="true" as well as android:backupAgent having the correct path to your projects FileBackupAgent. Also, your meta-data should have your registered key, such as android:value="your-registerd-key"

Make sure your device is connected to a Wi-Fi network. Also, make sure in your device Settings, the Backup and Reset needs to have "Back up my data" checked, and "Backup account" has a valid gmail account, and "Automatic restore" is checked.

In addition, in a command window, your transport settings should be: *com.google.android.backup/.BackupTransportService

You can see this by typing: bmgr list transports If transport is set to local, then enter: bmgr transport com.google.android.backup/.BackupTransportService

Other bmgr commands to use to "kick" start your backup in https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard are:

```
bmgr enabled 
bmgr wipe "your package in your manifest file"
bmgr backup "your package in your manifest file"
bmgr run
```

Refresh your https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard to see the latest backup timestamp